# IOS Page-based application: How to jump to another page

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uipageviewcontroller

I am new at this and I could use some help.

I am trying to make a button to move to the first (or any) page on the standard iOS Page-based application.
(I looked at several tutorials out there, but none helped...)

I started the new project, added a button at the Interface Buider (Main_iPhone.storyboard) connect it to a method in the DataViewController.m and I added the following code:

```
NSUInteger indexOfCurrentViewController = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:self];
DataViewController *myCurrentPage = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:indexOfCurrentViewController storyboard:self.storyboard];

indexOfCurrentViewController = 0; // or any number

DataViewController *myNextPage = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:indexOfCurrentViewController storyboard:self.storyboard];

[self presentViewController:myNextPage animated:YES completion:nil];
```

the code works, the new page is displayed on the simulator, but after there is no control active.

Its like the delegate (of the page) is not connected to the new page.

What am I missing? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `presentViewController`.  When you do, you are abandoning the UIPageViewController and passing control to DataViewController.  Instead, you want to update which ViewController is being shown within UIPageViewController.  So use
`[pageViewController setViewControllers:myNextPage direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil]`

Comment: Thanks. This is probably it. 

BTW, what's the best way to connect the RootViewController with the DataViewController ?